# How to keep zones disconnected in KiCad

Tags: kicad

I have a few zones and vias of the same net that should not connect (the ground return path of some components is sensitive). I currently use keepout areas, which is very time-consuming (strips around paths and zones).

Is there some way to prevent KiCad from connecting two zones or a via and a zone of the same net?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a via that connects a high speed switch to its ground return on layer In1.Cu (net class GND), but it automatically connects to the ground pour on layer In2.Cu, which has net class GND as well... Ideally, I would like to set a property to tell the via to not connect to layer In2.Cu or such

Comment: can ask on the specialized kicad.info website

Comment: Can you make them different nets? I use net ties all the time to make routing Kelvin connections easier.

Comment: Net ties sound interesting. Do you change the schematic and then tie it with graphical elements or can you change it in pcbnew?

Comment: I am just trying it, and it looks like a decent way, except I will need to change the footprints quite a bit to make them into NetTies